# Gradle not downloading dependencies linked to an artifact

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am trying to add an artifact to an Android project through Gradle (from a private repository I have set up, NOT from maven central), the direct artifact is downloaded just fine, but the dependencies from it are not being downloaded.

This is my code:

**POM of my main artifact:**

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>dependencyId</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**POM for the dependency artifact:**

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependencyId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
```

**Gradle code on the app:**

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "<private-url-repo>"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.example:artifactId:1.0.0@aar') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to do this after trying some stuff, so posting in case it helps anyone. The solution is to add `transitive = true;` to the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.example:artifactId:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;    
    }
}
```